# Left to right alignment in Toolbar

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I have a toolbar and i want to align the text to left instead of right.

The Main.xml file code is:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </include>
```

The code of app_bar_layout.xml is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_border_bottom"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/link_blue">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And the relevant code in Main java file is:

```
  mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        final String phoneLanguage = Locale.getDefault().toString();
        if (phoneLanguage.equals("iw_IL"))
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("פוליטיקה");
        }
        else
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Politico");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## include Textview in your app_bar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="right"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: My textColor was white and this is the reason for text invisibility. tnx a lot!

Comment: yeah, you just changed the text color of textview

Answer (score 1):

Do not set title Just add the TextView in Toolbar

**Here is demo**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Hi, if i put in a comment all the code in java file and add the Textview as you suggested, i got just empty white toolbar without any title....

Comment: My textColor was white and this is the reason for text invisibility. tnx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since your text is in Hebrew the Toolbar by default supports RTL for all RTL supported languages. I guess you are asking to override the RTL behaviour of your text.

In order to make your text left align add this attribute to your `Toolbar`

```
android:layoutDirection = "ltr"
```

Comment: My textColor was white and this is the reason for text invisibility. tnx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your entire app should be in RTL, you should go to `styles.xml` and add this to the AppTheme:

```
 <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
```

And, of course, do not forget to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` under the `application` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.